# Unit test for "ObservableCollection" method

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I'm new here and hope you can help me out.
I have a WPF application, here is the method that gets the object (TreeView in this case) and ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs (where I catch the current folder).

```
public static ObservableCollection<Folder> OnSelectionChanged(object sender, ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs itemSelection)
    {
        if (sender == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Can't be null", nameof(sender));
        }
        if (itemSelection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Can't be null", nameof(itemSelection));
        }

        var selected = itemSelection.AddedItems[0] as Folder;

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(selected.FullName.ToString());
        ObservableCollection<Folder> directories = new ObservableCollection<Folder>();

        directories = AddDirectoryInfo(directories, dirInfo);
        directories = AddFileInfo(directories, dirInfo);
        
        return directories;
    }
```

I need to write unit test for this method, but than i trying to initialize parametrs for transmitting into this methods i have exeptions.

```
private readonly string _folderName = "C:\\NewTestFolder";
[TestMethod()]
    public void OnSelectionChangedTest()
    {
        var sender = new SfTreeView() { Name = "treeSize" };

       var itemSelection = new ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs()
        {
            AddedItems = { new Folder()
            {
                FullName = _folderName,
                HasChildrenNodes = false,
                Modified = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                Name = "NewTestFolder",
                Size = "0",
                Type = "Folder"
            } },
            RemovedItems = { new Folder() { FullName = "" } }
        };


        var result = FolderView.OnSelectionChanged(sender, itemSelection);
    }
```

sender gives an error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread should be STA, since most UI components require it.'

itemSelection gives an error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Maybe I'm doing something wrong and these parameters to pass into the method should be set in some other way.

Comment: Sounds like a thread issue. Execute the test on a UI thread? In the context of a UI element?.. consider executing a similar set of tests with separate boundaries to give you coverage you need

Comment: I'd suggest given you don't use `sender` that you don't need it to be a `TreeView`. The second issue, if I was to guess, is that `AddedItems` and `RemovedItems` are null and collection initialiser syntax you're using effectively calls `Add` on them both.

Comment: @CharlesMager Oh, really, I don't use "sender" anywhere. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesMager but second issue is stil returned System.NullReferenceException.
I tryied to use: `itemSelection.AddedItems.Add(newFolder);` 
I think this is because AddItem has an "internal set"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks @CharlesMager for answer, i really missed that fact what i don't need "sender" parametr.

For this case, it helped me next,
i create new class ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs and inheriting him from current basic class and after that I redefine the variables AddedItems and RemoveItems, because in basic class they have "internal set" and after that i initialize new List.

```
AddedItems = new List<object>()
{ 
    new Folder()
    {
        FullName = _folderName,
        HasChildrenNodes = false,
        Modified = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
        Name = "NewTestFolder",
        Size = "0",
        Type = "Folder"
    } 
},
RemovedItems = new List<object>()
{ 
    new Folder() 
}
```